# Unreal Engine 4: Spawn Emitter At Location

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I used the First Person Template in the Unreal Engine 4.17.2 and chose to use C++ instead of blueprint. My goal was to make the projectile that's shooting out of the gun in the template explode on contact with whatever it made contact with after being shot out. I planned to use the explosion particle in the starter content. To do so I opened up the projectile class that comes in the template and edit the code for both the header file and source file in Visual Studio 2017. [Here you can see I where I establish a particle system in the header file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZkyB.png)

Although in the source file I have an issue trying to use `UGameplayStatics::SpawnEmitterAtLocation`

[This is after using #include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9vKe.png)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this, I was having trouble to spawn my particle systems although everything was compiling without problems and the same function performing exactly what I wanted in Blueprints.
Turns out you need both

```
#include "Runtime/Engine/Classes/Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"
#include "Runtime/Engine/Classes/Kismet/KismetSystemLibrary.h"
```

to be able to use the `UGameplayStatics::SpawnEmitterAtLocation` in C++.

Comment: Never mind my last post, what happened to me was something else, apparently the Overlap events do not populate the hitResult struct, so I was spawning my particle system effect in the FVector(0,0,0).  In case anyone doing a slash damage effect needs to be precise, they can do a line trace from the base to the tip of their sword, like this suggestion: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/741853/get-sweep-result-from-oncomponentbeginoverlap.html?sort=oldest